# widgetVar name collision in Primefaces in multiple cc:renderFacet

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have composite component, in which I have **toolbar** and **datatable**. I also defined **facet** which contains a form for manipulating data from datatable. Users define that facet for different kinds of data. Now, I have problem because I **render that facet multiple times** and now I have **collisions for widgetVar names for Primefaces components**. It is no possible to use **insertChildren** multiple times so I think this is only possible solution. Also I wouldn't like to force users of component to define 10 facets and write ui:include 10 times. Is there any other way to insert some facelet code in composite component, or is there any way to pass parameter to facet, and use that parameter to dynamically create widgetVar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after some time I just didn't succeeded to do what I wanted. First I had some composite component like this:

```
<cc:interface>
  <!-- Attributes definition -->
  <cc:facet name="form"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
  <p:dialog><f:subview id="detailSubview1"><cc:renderFacet name="form"/></f:subview></p:dialog>
  <p:dialog><f:subview id="detailSubview2"><cc:renderFacet name="form"/></f:subview></p:dialog>
  <!-- There is some more renderFacets but this is enough -->
</cc:implementation>
```

If I have for example `p:selectOneMenu` inside the form, without any `widgetVar` definitions, all will be with same name for `widgetVar` and this is a problem.

So, I changed this completely and I will transform this composite component to `ui:composition` and decorate it in my page. In that case widget vars are generated as I want, with different names, because they are in different naming containers.

Answer (score 1):

A `widgetVar` is in fact used in JavaScript to identify the component. Therefor a `widgetVar` must be unique in a page. You'll have to declare it yourself.

If you want to create a custom component, as I think might suit you better than `ui:define`/`ui:include`, you might want to do something like this:

Say we want to create a component that renders a `p:commandButton` and a `h:outputText` with the same value (for whatever reason). You create a XHTML page in directory `[deployed-root]/resources/example`, named `customComponent.xhtm`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <c:interface>
        <c:attribute name="text" required="true" />
    </c:interface>
    <c:implementation>
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.text}" />
        <p:commandButton value="#{cc.attrs.text}" />
    </c:implementation>
</html>
```

Then to use this in another page you'll have to define the namespace `xmlns:e="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/example"`, and then you can refer to the custom component like this: `<e:customComponent text="some text here"/>`.

It should also be noted that it is bad practice to declare forms in custom components. This affects flexibility of use drastically since forms cannot be nested.

Comment: I have little bit different situation here. A have one part of xhtml code (it is not important if it is form or something else), and I need to include that part of xhtml code on for example 10 places in my composite component. If I provide widgetVar, that would not be good because I will have 10 same widgetVar names. I can define 10 facets, and Primefaces will than generate different widgetVars, but I want to avoid this.

Comment: If you don't want PrimeFaces to generate widgetVars you can go with my example above and define an attribute "widgetVar". This is simply not possible with `ui:include`/`ui:define`. If you still want to use `ui:include` you'll have the same widgetVars or you'll have to let Primefaces generate them.

Comment: I'm using `cc:renderFacet` to put content. I just wont to let user to open for example 10 detail dialogs, and I want to reuse same form for all dialogs, so I rendered that facet 10 times. Also I left Primefaces to generate `widgetVar`, but it generated the same for all 10 rendered facets.

Comment: @partlov Maybe you should post a [short self contained correct example](http://sscce.org) to demonstrate your problem. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces can generate `wigetVar`s so you don't have to.

From the 3.4 User's Guide:

```xhtml
<p:dialog id="dlg">
    <!-- contents -->
</p:dialog>
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Show" onclick="#{p:widgetVar('dlg')}.show();"/>
```

This is designed to work in naming containers, so it should work just fine in composite components, `<ui:repeat/>`, `<h:dataTable/>`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work in multiple `renderFacet`. Dialog widget vars are not problem, bu widget vars inside form. In the example from my answer if I have `<p:selectOneMenu>` in form, I will have two same widgetVars. Try it on your own and you will see. Just inspect generated HTML. In `ui:repeat` that's OK, with facets it is different thing. Their code is just copied where you put `renderFacet`.